# How can I count all the comments in a tree?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a threaded comment system and an trying to figure out a way of counting how many comments are below any given comment in the hierarchy. As of now each comment JSON object has a property called hasChildren which is an integer incremented every time someone replies to that comment. That means that hasChildren only keeps track of direct replies and not replies to replies.

Take this diagram:

```
OP--1.1--2.1--3.1
 |  
 1.2--2.2--3.2--4.1
      |    |
      |    4.2--5.1
      |
      3.3--4.3--5.2
```

How would I figure out how many comments are children, grandchildren, etc. of comment 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i've done it is structure every comment like so:

```
{
  parent: _id,
  ancestors: [_id, _id]
}
```

where parent is the direct parent and ancestors are every parent comment above the ancestor chain. the first ancestor shouldn't be a comment (the post)

So suppose you have comment 1.2 that looks like so:

```
comment = {
  _id: _id,
  parent: OP._id,
  ancestors: [OP._id]
}
```

children:

```
db.comments.find({
  'parent': comment._id,
})
```

grandchildren:

```
db.comments.find({
  'ancestors.1': comment._id,
  'ancestors': {
    $size: 3
  }
})
```

all descendants:

```
db.comments.find({
  'ancestors.1': comment._id
})
```

then for indexes, you can do `parent`, `ancestors.1`, and, say, `ancestors.6`

## Creating comments

here's a simplified example on how to create a comment

```
function Comment(parent) {
  this.parent = parent._id
  this.ancestors = (parent.ancestors || []).concat(parent._id)
}

var comment = new Comment(originalPost)
var child = new Comment(comment)
var grandchild = new Comment(child)
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm still a bit confused. How would you build the ancestors array for, say, comment 3.2?

Comment: also, this will require changing your schema.

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing your schema.  There is a great example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/category-hierarchy/) which shows how you can store a hierarchy and how you can query it.